# How to redirect http post request to https post request via proxy in nginx

Tags: nginx, https, proxy

I want to redirect a http post request to https post request.Is there a way to complete it through the proxy configuration in nginx.
I find a blog in the http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-ssl/. And I have a try like this:

```
upstream backends {
   server 192.168.100.100:443;
}

server {
   listen              80;
   server_name         www.example.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass https://backends; 
   }
}
```

But it returned a 502 bad gateway result when I curl it like this:
curl -X POST 'http://www.example.com/a.json' --data-binary 'name=super'

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the 308 redirect instead of 301 (former keeps the method and latter mutates POSTs to GETs):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This works. One caveat -- you have to upgrade to Nginx +1.13.x. You'll see that support for 308 was added in April 2017.